# How do I use loops in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

EDIT:
I have a ItemList : Dim ItemList As New List(Of String)
I wanna append each element from itemlist to a new list for 10 times each, then to start over again.
How can I make a loop for each element while there are still elements in the list (10 times each)?

I tried this but it's not working. it's too complicated for me cause I'm a newbie

```
    Private crt As Integer = 0
    Private limit As Integer = 0

    Private Function getline() As String
    Dim line As String = ""
        SyncLock addlines
            Do While limit < 10
                line = ItemList(crt)
                limit += 1
            Loop
            limit = 0
            crt += 1
        End SyncLock

    addlines.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & line & " limit:" & limit & " crt:" & crt)
    'Return line
End Function
```

thanks

I have also tried this:

```
 For Each I As Item In Items
   If I = x Then Continue For

   ' Do something
   Next
```

but I didn't know where to add the 10 times limit and also the current item number(crt)

Comment: May I suggest reading up on "For...Next Loops"?

Comment: Also, your question doesn't make much sense as worded. Can you edit it to be more clear what you want?

Comment: I already did that and tried with for each and continue for but still doesn't work. I guess I'm not that smart

Comment: I have no idea what you are even asking, to be honest. You may be smart, but communication seems to be the problem here.

Comment: It might be best if you described the contents of ItemList and the output you expect to see. Your edit didn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can make out of that mess of a question, you seem to want to append each line in ItemList (whatever that object is) 10 times.

This should do the trick.

```
Dim limit as integer=10

For each line as string in ItemList
   For lineNum as integer = 1 to limit
      addlines.AppendText(string.format("{0}{1} Limit: {2} CRT:{3}", Environment.NewLine, line, limit, lineNum ))
   Next lineNum 
Next line
```

**Update:** Updated answer for explanation in comments about what CRT was.

Comment: thank you, I'm trying it right now. crt is the current item number in list and limit is the max number which is 10

Comment: I have to define limit like this: "Private limit As Integer = 0" outside the function and after I added your code I get this error: The type for variable 'limit' will not be inferred because it is bound to a field in an enclosing scope. Either change the name of 'limit', or use the fully qualified name (for example, 'Me.limit' or 'MyBase.limit')

Comment: the only problem right now is that I'm using 5 threads to invoke that function and the limit instead of being 100 is 5 :(

Comment: Yeah. That sounds like a really bad idea. If you are still learning how to do loops, you might want to avoid trying to tackle multi-threaded applications. Get the basics down first then move on to the advanced stuff.